# will users see post on their wall,if a post is made on app page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I would like to know, if a post is made by an app on a page which is associated with the app, then the posts published on that page will be shown on users wall or not, provided that users have allowed access to that app.

Comment: unless user is subscribed to that page, it does!

Comment: user is subscribed to the app, not to the page associated with the app, what I am looking for is sending some kind of "notification" to the user via the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, users of your applications who are not fans of associated page will not get posts published on that page appears on their wall (associated page it's still a page, nothing unusual here).

You can place [Like Box social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) in your application so your users will be able to like associated page and get subscribed on updates.